# Update SharePoint file field that is of type choice muliple selection

Tags: sharepoint, caml

I am using UpdateListItems method (Lists.asmx web service) to update fields of an uploaded document in one SharePoint document library. In my case, I have a document library called Schedules. In it, there's a field called 'Day of the Week' which is a Choice multiple selection, with the allowed values Monday to Sunday. Here's the query that I have found which should select Monday and Friday choices (and it doesn't work, obviously):

```
<Method ID='1' Cmd='Update'>
    <Field Name='ID'>1</Field>
    <Field Name='Day of the Week'>Monday#;Friday</Field>
</Method>
```

I have read somewhere that inserting the string "#;" between the choices should resolve this. The end result is that the field Day of the Week is updated with the string "Monday#;Friday" and when I want to edit the item, no selection is being made. On the other hand if I just use "Monday", it works. Now, how can I make it update the multiple selection? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that should be `;#`

A quick check shows the way SharePoint stores multi-choice fields, try:

> ;#Monday;#Friday;#

With the delimiter on the beginning and the end.

And a note: You should also keep in mind that SharePoint stores choices as plain text (not references), so you can place any value there, as you've just witnessed.

Comment: That is correct. So, in the end it was a typo. OK, is there a way to make the string "Monday;#Friday" appear  as "Monday; Friday", i.e. normally, as it would if I made this selection through SharePoint UI? Having the characted '#' in the middle is confusing to the viewer. Help please?